# Microstrategy - how to create a custom group with boolean band

Tags: sql, report, microstrategy

So, I've had this problem in my hands for the last couples of days and it drives me crazy.

I have a bunch of table that looks like this:

[Fact table 1, Lookup for stores that maps StoreID and StoreRegion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO2kC.png)

[Fact table 2, cointains StoreID, CustomerID, and information about Sales quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbB5D.png)

My aim is to have something like that:

[Final result desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LYYK.png)

So a report in which the users can select two regions (from a prompt) and then the reports show how many customers (the metric N_SCO is basically a count(Customers)) have a sale in both regions, and how much they spent, how many customers have a sale only in the first region and how much they spent, how many customers have a sale only in the second region and how much they spent.

I've tried to mess up with custom groups, I think it's the answer and it's driving me insane. Can someone lend me a hand? I don't understand how I have to break by the metric in the custom group or which type of band I should use to get a result like that. I know it's possible, I've seen it but I cannot acces the SQL behind it cause it was like one year ago in my previous company, I just don't get how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was

create 2 similar region prompt ( call it region 1 & region 2)
now create 2 revenue metric , region1 revenue ( with region 1 prompt in filter) and region 2 revenue ( with region 2 prompt in filter)
in custom group band could be like following
YY - region1 revenue > 0 AND region 2 revenue > 0

YN - region1 revenue > 0 AND region 2 revenue = 0 or null

NY - region1 revenue = 0 or null AND region 2 revenue > 0

By ManishaGupta that reached out to me via Microstrategy Community